# Suggestions for Canadian (Metro Vancouver) Housing Open Data Sources

Tags: data-request, canada, real-estate

before doing data analysis, I have to find public data sources first. The goal is to find housing services related data, or people data related to these housing services, in different regions of Metro Vancouver.
Especially focus on those housing aims at improve individual well being or community well being.

I searched for many lists of this type of services, checking their websites, social media or reading their reports, but could not find public data for my data analysis.

I have also checked Canada Council, Statistics Canada, they don't have specific data for regions in Metro Vancouver...

Do you have any suggestions to find this type of data contains Metro Vancouver regional info?

Comment: I don't think this is a great question for this site. However, take a peek at this post: [datasets](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7/locating-freely-available-data-samples).

Comment: Questions asking for datasets are off topic here. This question could be on topic on the [opendata.SE] SE site, though. We will try to get it migrated there.

Comment: I would consider looking at and using the APIs for Canada's equivalent of Zillow (http://www.zillow.com/research/data/)

Comment: In case you find it helpful, Quandl has free data from the Canadian Mortgage and Housing Corporation (CMHC) here: https://www.quandl.com/data/CMHC

Answer (score 4):

Metro Vancouver has an open data catalogue
http://www.metrovancouver.org/data

These geo datasets are available:

```
Frequent Transit Development Areas
Land Use
Metro 2040 Land Designation
Metro 2040 Urban Containment
Metro Vancouver Regional Park Trails
Municipal Boundaries
Private Licensed Solid Waste Facilities
Public Solid Waste Facilities
Special Study Areas
Urban Centre
```

Answer (score 3):

[Search Canada Mortgage and Housing Corporation for Vancouver](https://www.cmhc-schl.gc.ca/en/search/search_001.cfm?sec=en&text=Vancouver)
[CMHC Housing Market Information Portal](https://www03.cmhc-schl.gc.ca/hmiportal/en/#Profile/1/1/Canada)
[Search Open Canada for "Housing"](http://recherche-search.gc.ca/rGs/s_r?q=housing&wb-srch-sub=search&num=10&langs=eng&st1rt=0&st=s&s5bm3ts21rch=x&cdn=canada&delta=1&form_build_id=form-7WXKDFtD2EfxmwC0jqyUtJYPoUD55LQdqny6FihwZno&form_id=custom_search_blocks_form_1&custom_search_paths=search%2Fsite%2F%5Bkey%5D#wb-land)